Spark Pools in Microsoft Fabric: "Autoscale" versus "Dynamically allocate executors"
EDIT: I'm adding a short intro to the question to make it clearer.
I understand how the two setting Autoscale and Dynamic executors work and what they do. What I don't understand is the purpose or benefit of the 2nd setting. When/why would I want to configure fewer executors than nodes, underutilizing my available nodes? Maybe an example can help.
Now the question context:
How do the settings "Autoscale" and "Dynamically allocate executors" work in Synapse?
If I have my pool configured to scale from 1 to 30 nodes, I can set the number of dynamic exeutors to 29 max (number of nodes minus one driver node).
Why are there two settings? I cannot have more executors than nodes, can I?
And if there is only one executor per node, what if I set the number of executors to a lower value? Will my notebook than reserve more nodes than required?


Autoscale will adjust the number of nodes  based on workload demand. When you set a range, the system will automatically add or remove nodes as needed. It will check some metrics like CPU and memory usage to make these decisions.
Dynamically allocate executors will manage the allocation of executors within the available nodes so they run the actual tasks in Spark, and dynamic allocation allows Spark to automatically adjust the number of executors based on the workload.
Why 2 settings ?
The 1st one simply manages the nodes that provide the compute power.
The 2nd one manages the executors (software processes in another word) within those nodes.
You can't have more executors than the number of available nodes. Each node can run one executor (don't forget that it is excluding the driver node). So if you have 30 nodes, you can allocate a maximum of 29 executors.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-autoscale
If you set a lower number of executors than the available nodes, Spark will only use the configured number of executors, and the nodes which are not used will be decommissioned or left idle (depending on the scaling needs) so Spark will not unnecessarily reserve more nodes than required​.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/dynamic-allocation-for-apache-spark-in-azure-synapse-now-generally-available/

Thanks for explaining what the settings do. But the aspect of "why 2 settings" is still unclear. If num of executors is lower then num of nodes, the max number of nodes will always be capped by the max number of executors. This makes the max number of nodes setting useless.

Autoscale governs infrastructure resources in other words the actual physical or virtual nodes that can be added or removed based on workload.
Dynamic Allocation governs executor processes, the Spark tasks that run on those nodes.

The 1st  option adjusts the hardware (nodes) based on demand while the 2nd option fine-tunes how those nodes are used by adjusting the number of executors running on them.

I get what you're saying. What I don't understand is the purpose or benefit of the 2nd setting. When/why would I want to configure fewer executors than nodes, underutilizing my available hardware? Maybe an example can help.
